# how to code activity page... android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new to android and I am learning from tutorials. What I am trying to do is link 2 xml pages. After login go to content page. The problem is when I add intent code in my class file the emulator provides the error msg "the app has stopped working" else the code is working perfectly.

This is the intent code I have tried:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), secondpage.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
```

I also tried this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondpage.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

and last, this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondpage.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

my secondpage.class code is given below (the name of the xml file is cf)

```
public class secondpage extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cf);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does the intent cause the emulator to flash the error msg?

my manifest.xml

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.qwedd.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

my log cat

```
02-10 03:07:49.440: D/dalvikvm(903): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-10 03:07:52.290: D/dalvikvm(903): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 5% free 2890K/3016K, paused 39ms, total 41ms
02-10 03:07:52.370: I/dalvikvm-heap(903): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.512MB for 10092616-byte allocation
02-10 03:07:52.440: D/dalvikvm(903): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 2% free 12744K/12876K, paused 65ms, total 65ms
02-10 03:07:54.010: D/(903): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb81424b8, tid 903
02-10 03:07:54.080: W/EGL_emulation(903): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-10 03:07:54.090: D/OpenGLRenderer(903): Enabling debug mode 0
02-10 03:08:00.020: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(903): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
02-10 03:08:00.020: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(903):   in android.widget.EditText{b3d9ea80 VFED..CL .F...... 15,315-465,374 #7f080001 app:id/txtPassword}
02-10 03:08:00.020: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(903):   0: sent at 103941000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=103941, downTime=103804, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
02-10 03:08:38.556: D/AndroidRuntime(903): Shutting down VM
02-10 03:08:38.556: W/dalvikvm(903): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aeaba8)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903): Process: com.example.qwedd, PID: 903
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.qwedd/com.example.qwedd.secondpage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at com.example.qwedd.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 03:09:23.546: I/Process(903): Sending signal. PID: 903 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post the manifest and the stacktrace

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` or your error from LogCat

Comment: May be you did't put secondpage activity to your manifest file. put this line after your main activity tag <activity android:name=".secondpage"></activity>

Comment: Did you declare `secondpage` in the manifest? ... the logcat shows what's wrong

Comment: your logcat asks you in this line: 02-10 03:08:38.566: E/AndroidRuntime(903): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.qwedd/com.example.qwedd.secondpage}; **have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**  So you have to declare every activity in your manifest

Comment: Thank you for ur prompt comments.. the mistake was not declaring in my activity manifest.. thank you all.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, Every Activity needs it's own xml layout file (unless using more advanced methods, probably that is not your intention anyhow).

in the onCreate method you see the `setContentView(R.layout.cf);` - meaning this activity is calling the layout xml called "cf".

So, if you want two activities and you want to go from one to other - do the following:

1) in the first activity, in the onCreate method, call your first layout file like so:

```
 public class firstActivity extends Activity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstlayout);        

}
```

In your second activity, in the onCreate method, call your second layout file like so:

```
public class secondActivity extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondlayout);        

    }
```

If you have more than one activity, you need to declare them in your manifest.xml
for example:

```
<activity android:name=".secondPage" >    </activity>
```

Now, in your first Activity, you will want to go to second activity usually when you press a button or something.
so, in your onClickListener (or wherever you want to go to second page), you call an Intent like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(firstPage.this, secondPage.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: thankyou gilonm.. the code works.. more importantly.. thanks for the explanation... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to add activity to your Manifest file. If it is so then check your manifest file that you have declared `seconpage` activity in manifest file. Or if it is not added then add it as below.

add it as below.

```
 <activity android:name=".seconpage" >
        </activity>
```

add this line after completing your first activity tag.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`

Your app didn't able to find `secondpage` Activity in your app. so first you have to register every `Activity` to your manifest file before using them.

```
<activity android:name=".secondpage"></activity>
```

and for calling this you can use

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondpage.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: do i have to provide packagename.classname or just .classname??

Comment: no need. but your activity in different packages so put the packagename.classname... @user3060890

Comment: Thank you psk.. its working..  also even if we give package.classname and just .classname.. the code works..